# Python Pandas - Find the index of the result of a formula returning a single value from a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pd.Series` and an integer:

```
a = pd.Series([0, 7, 3, 14, 9, 12, 13])
b = 8
```

the following formula compute the maximum of the absolute value of the difference `a - b`:

```
f(a) = max(abs(a-b))
```

in our case:

```
a-b= [-8, -1, -5, 6, 1, 4, 5]
abs(a-b) = [8, 1, 5, 6, 1, 4, 5]
f(a) = max(abs(a-b)) = 8
```

I would like to compute the index of the Series for `f(a)`.
(In that case it should be `0`)

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only care about the first occurrence of the maximum value, you can use `idxmax()`:

```
(a - b).abs().idxmax()
# 0
```